# Generating comparison from same table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to create a query that shows

- number of members at a certain period, and
- the members for a different period with the same organization.

This is for generating historical comparisons.

Currently I have 2 identical tables to accomplish this, but I'm trying to generate it with queries.

Currently I have 2 identical queries as follows:

```
SELECT CU_Info.CU_Name, Membership.Period, 
  Membership.[Membership_#],CU_Info.Province
FROM CU_Info
INNER JOIN Membership
ON CU_Info.CU_Name = Membership.CU_Name
WHERE (((Membership.Period)=[Forms]![Members_By_Province]![cboPeriodProvince])
AND ((CU_Info.Province)=[Forms]![Members_By_Province]![cboProvince]));
```

Then another to combine and compare the 2 queries:

```
SELECT qryNowProv.CU_Name, qryNowProv.[Membership_#],
  qryCompProv.CU_Name, qryCompProv.[Membership_#], qryCompProv.Province
FROM qryNowProv, qryCompProv;
```

This results in the following:

```
Bank1, 1000, Bank1, 9000, QE
Bank1, 1000, Bank2, 9500, QE
```

With repeating information in Now column and looping data in the Compare column. I'd like it compare the same banks membership numbers but at different time periods (for growth comparisons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably start off doing this with some simple subqueries, one to return the membership count at each date:

```
SELECT first_period.CU_Name, first_membership, second_membership
second_membership - firt_membership AS membership_difference
FROM
(
  SELECT CU_Name, [Membership_#] AS first_membership
  FROM Membership
  WHERE Period = 1
) first_period
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT CU_Name, [Membership_#] AS first_membership
  FROM Membership
  WHERE Period = 2
) second_period
ON first_period.CU_Name = second_period.CU_Name
```

Obviously you'll need to adjust this to your specific requirements (particularly `WHERE Period = whatever`) but that should get you started.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Is this exactly what you were looking for? Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sum by case statements to do this faster.

```
SELECT CU_Info.CU_Name, [Forms] ! [Members_By_Province] ! [cboPeriodProvince] AS Period, SUM(CASE 
            WHEN (Membership.Period) = [Forms] ! [Members_By_Province] ! [cboPeriodProvince]
                THEN Membership.[Membership_#]
            ELSE 0
            END) PeriodMembership, SUM(CASE 
            WHEN (Membership.Period) = [Forms] ! [Members_By_Province] ! [cboPeriodProvince]
                THEN 0
            ELSE Membership.[Membership_#]
            END) OutsidePeriodMembership, CU_Info.Province
FROM CU_Info
INNER JOIN Membership ON CU_Info.CU_Name = Membership.CU_Name
WHERE (
        ((Membership.Period) =)
        AND ((CU_Info.Province) = [Forms] ! [Members_By_Province] ! [cboProvince])
        );

GROUP BY CU_Info.CU_Name, CU_Info.Province
```